# Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout

Tags: android

Trying to update my app to material, i get this problem when i launch the app on my emulator. The app Force Closes.

whole log [here](http://pastebin.com/s8fMZcgr)

I have updated and re-imported my appcompatv7 many times now, still no luck. My activities extend ActionBarActivity.

Any help? What can i do to stop my app from Force Closing?

Comment: Any luck with this? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @Xelz Unfortunteky not. By any chance do you have the CardsUI library installed? As I actually managed to stop the issue by removing CardsUI, but unfortunately that library makes up 85% of my app, so I'm back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 1):

Change your styles.xml code to like this

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using AppCompat textAppearance (ex: @style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium)?
These are not supported in API14 and will crash your app at ActionBarOverlayLayout.
You should use ?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well after installing the Android plugin and SDK for Eclipse. Restarting Eclipse did not fix it, but restarting my PC worked.